# for loops in R runs with the last file only

Tags: r

There are 5 files in the folder, but when I runs for loop, it just works with one file and that file is the last one, not the first one as in the sequence.

```
files <- dir('~/disciplines/demo/')
metadata <- read.csv('~/disciplines/demo/metadata.csv')
filenames <- metadata$id
for (i in 1:length(filenames)) {
  text <- scan(file=paste('~/disciplines/demo/folder/', filenames[i], '.txt', sep=''), what='char', sep='\n')
  tokens <- unlist(strsplit(text, '\\W+'))
}
# Read 1 item
# Read 1 item
# Read 1 item
# Read 1 item
# Read 1 item
```

I tried different ways but it didn't work.

Comment: You overwrite `tokens` each time in the loop so only the last value will be there when the loop is done.. What exactly are you expecting to happen? Also if you are just reading lines without splitting `readLines` would probably be easier to use than `scan`

Comment: E.g. save tokens in a list to save the read content: before for-loop, write `token_list = list()` and then as last line in the for-loop save the content of token in the list, e.g. `token_list[i] <- token`. Also I would suggest using `read.csv` instead of the `scan`method.

Comment: Hi, I want to split the texts into separate tokens. I expect to have tokens for each of the file but it works with the last file only.

Comment: since this is in txt, can it work with read.csv?

Comment: Also, for safety, consider switching from a `for` loop to `lapply` to avoid potential issues with [lazy evaluation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#lazy-evaluation).

Comment: @Limey with no function definitions in the loop what potential lazy evaluation issues are here?  I don't see any.

Comment: @GregorThomas The code in OP's loop produces no console output, yet "output" appears immediately after it, therefore I see an unexplained inconsistency.  Personally, having been bitten (too) many times in the past by lazy evaluation in `for` loops, I now generally turn to the `apply` family as a first option to avoid the problem.  My comment was intended as friendly advice rather than a definitive answer.

Comment: Many functions print messages to the console as they run.

Comment: Before the loop create `tokens <- vector("list", length = length(filenames))` and in the loop change to `tokens[[i]] <- unlist(strsplit(text, '\\W+'))`.